# Javascript, Regex-Split multi-line string by linebreak OR semicolon, unless in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a small language parser for a project and I need to split a multi-line string/file by either a semicolon or a line-break, unless they're within quotes (") - if possible in a single regex statement.

I've tried the following combinations:

```
split(/^([\r\n]+|[;])(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"])/);
```

and

```
split(/(".*?"|[^;]|[^\r\n])(?=\s*;|\s*\r\n)/);
```

but none of them quite works out.

Example:

Fu; Bar; Some"thing;"
Fubar;

should result in the following array:

Fu;
Bar;
Some"asd;asd"
Fubar;

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of selecting 'thing', select another custom text?

Comment: what is `"asd;asd"` in your result array?

Comment: Is there any problem? @NeverSink

Answer (score 0):

First Capturing Group in this pattern is what you want (and should) extract:

```
(?:"[^"]*"|;|^|\n)([^"\n]+?)(?=;|"|\n)
```

https://regex101.com/r/v2vz1Z/3

Description:

- find each ; or any "..." or starting of line ^
- extract characters [^"] that is not "
- till find new ; or "